# String Data transformation Processing 300MB having 30M records in Dask Distributed

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

Starting Dask Scheduler on Node1 (4CPU, 8GB):

Dask Scheduler: `dask-scheduler --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8786`

Starting Workers on Node2(8CPU, 32GB) and Node3 (8CPU, 32GB):
Dask Worker:

`dask-worker tcp://http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8786 --nanny-port 3000:3004 --worker-port 3100:3104 --dashboard-address :8789`

Here is my prototype, redacted `some_private_processing` and `some_processing` methods:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

from dask.distributed import Client

N_CORES = 16
THREADS_PER_WORKER = 2
dask_cluster = Client(
    '127.0.0.1:8786'
)

def get_clean_str1(str1):
    ret_tuple = None, False, True, None, False
    if not str1:
        return ret_tuple
    if string_validators(str1) is not True:
        return ret_tuple

    data = some_processing(str1)
    match_flag = False
    if str1 == data.get('formated_str1'):
        match_flag = True

    private_data = some_private_processing(str1)
    private_match_flag = False
    if str1 == private_data.get('formated_private_str1'):
        private_match_flag = True
    ret_tuple = str1, match_flag, False, private_str1, private_match_flag
    return ret_tuple

files = [
    'part-00000-abcd.gz.parquet',
    'part-00001-abcd.gz.parquet',
    'part-00002-abcd.gz.parquet',
]
print('Starting...')
for idx, each_file in enumerate(files):
    dask_cluster.restart()
    print(f'Processing file {idx}: {each_file}')
    all_str1s_df = pd.read_parquet(
        each_file,
        engine='pyarrow'
    )
    print(f'Read file {idx}: {each_file}')
    all_str1s_df = dd.from_pandas(all_str1s_df, npartitions=16000)
    print(f'Starting file processing {idx}: {each_file}')
    str1_res_tuple = all_str1s_df.map_partitions(
        lambda part: part.apply(
            lambda x: get_clean_str1(x['str1']),
            axis=1
        ),
        meta=tuple
    )

    (clean_str1,
     match_flag,
     bad_str1_flag,
     private_str1,
     private_match_flag) = zip(*str1_res_tuple)

    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df.assign(
        clean_str1=pd.Series(clean_str1)
    )
    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df.assign(
        match_flag=pd.Series(match_flag)
    )
    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df.assign(
        bad_str1_flag=pd.Series(bad_str1_flag)
    )
    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df.assign(
        private_str1=pd.Series(private_str1)
    )
    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df.assign(
        private_match_flag=pd.Series(private_match_flag)
    )
    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df[
        all_str1s_df['match_flag'] == False
    ]
    all_str1s_df = all_str1s_df.repartition(npartitions=200)
    all_str1s_df.to_csv(
        f'results-str1s-{idx}-*.csv'
    )
    print(f'Finished file {idx}: {each_file}')
```

This processing is taking more than 8hours and I see all the data is being processed only on one node either on Node2 or Node3 but not on both Node2 and Node3.

Need help to understand the insights and to understand where I am doing wrong to make this simple data transformation to run for more than 8hours and still not yet completed.

Answer (score 0):

Increased timeouts, increased memory. After that, it started working, without failing and hanging.

```
timeouts:
  connect: 180s          # time before connecting fails
  tcp: 180s              # time before calling an unresponsive connection dead
```